# Check State of check box as checked or Not?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, getattribute

I am trying to verify if the state of a check box is checked or not if the state is false click if not do something else. Should i use .getAttribute() or .getState(). I think I should use get state.

```
 WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.name("companyOptionsForm:mandateVerificationTotals"));

     if (checkbox.getState() == true) {
      //do something
     } else if (checkbox.getState()== false) {
      //do something
     }
```

The HTML of the Check box

```
< input name = "companyOptionsForm:mandateVerificationTotals"
type = "checkbox"role = "checkbox"aria - checked = "true"
class = "dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput"data - dojo - attach - point = "focusNode"
data - dojo - attach - event = "ondijitclick:_onClick"
value = "on"tabindex = "0"id = "mandateVerificationTotals"
checked = "checked" style = "user-select: none;" >
```

However when i use .getState() eclipse shows a red line under it.

Comment: Can you update the question with the _HTML_ for both `unchecked` and `checked` state of the _Check Box_?

Comment: try `checkBox.isSelected()`

Comment: it is the same code the only different is if box is checked checked =true if not checked = false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like this:

```
WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.name("companyOptionsForm:mandateVerificationTotals"));

if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
  //do something
 } else  {
  //do something else
 }
```

Comment: I will try this question. isSelected is it Boolean? nvm it is Boolean

Answer (score 2):

An AWT Checkbox has a method called getState(), but not a method called isSelected().

A Swing JCheckBox has a method called isSelected(), but not one called getState().

And as @Arthur showed, do not compare a boolean to true of false; just use 
`if (booleanVariable)` or `if (!booleanVariable)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `javascript` to verify if checkbox is selected

```
public boolean isChecked(WebElement element) {
    return (boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].checked", element);
}
```

Comment: This did not work that well for me but the answer above did. Thank you